# Option to migrate to Super User?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Prompted by [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7353/is-there-a-way-to-search-for-an-opened-tab-in-all-currently-opened-windows-of-goo)

Are we going to have an option on the close menu to migrate questions to Super User (if appropriate)?

Now that a better "off topic" migration dialog has been implemented - [Adapt close dialog UI for upcoming avalanche of StackExchange 2.0 graduates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63961/adapt-close-dialog-ui-for-upcoming-avalanche-of-stackexchange-2-0-graduates) - when are the Super User and (possibly) Web Masters options going to be added to ours.

In response to Jeff's answer here are a selection of questions from the first two pages of search for "closed:1":

## Web Masters

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/53/what-are-the-top-tools-you-need-as-a-web-applications-developer-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/307/can-anyone-reccomend-a-free-web-hosting-site-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/543/how-do-i-implement-url-rewriting-in-my-htaccess-file-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/how-do-i-prevent-xss-attacks-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/what-is-the-best-relational-database-management-system-dbms-to-use-with-a-web-a
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/what-are-the-implications-of-changing-the-settings-of-thread-limit-in-my-tomcat-a
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/django-vs-google-app-engine-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/do-you-monitor-referers-to-your-websites-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3501/recommendations-on-how-to-auction-a-domain-name-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3553/what-are-good-practices-to-grow-a-web-applications-user-base-from-0-to-100k-clo

## Super User

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/how-do-i-get-my-slow-windows-installation-to-run-faster-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2393/what-is-the-best-pdf-organizer-on-local-desktop-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/ripping-cds-to-mp3-format-using-itunes-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/google-chrome-bookmark-syncing-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3200/is-it-possible-to-set-font-family-for-html-mail-in-outlook-2003-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/page-setup-option-in-chrome-closed

## Stack Overflow

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/551/whats-wrong-with-the-javascript-engine-in-safari-5-on-my-intel-imac-closed
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3198/javascript-libraries-that-provide-support-for-scrolling-tree-like-node-display

## User Interface

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3145/augmented-reality-marker-size-how-small-can-it-be-closed

## Wordpress

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117/best-last-fm-plugin-for-wordpress-closed

## On Startups

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/buy-partner-out-of-business-startup-closed

Comment: I hope so.  If they can migrate here it makes sense for it to be a two-way street.

Comment: Chris - Wouldnt some of the above listed items be more apt for Software Recs?

Comment: @Alex - this was written long before Software Recommendations existed, so you're probably right. However SR is quite strict about what's on topic, so it probably wouldn't work if it was a standard migration target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly, but to make a case for migration we need to see evidence that these questions are asked in some quantity here and then closed.

So.. start linking :)

edit: based on your links, I think we can support migrations between:

> Web Apps -> Super User
>   Web Apps -> Pro Webmasters

everything else should just be flagged for moderator attention and arbitrarily migrated on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Less-used migration paths could maybe be [offered based on question tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)? This way a path to [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) will only show for questions tagged `[wordpress]`.